# Redirecting ALL links from specified directory to specified file

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

Is there a way to redirect all links from: `mydomain.com/dir/$$$$$$$$$$` to `mydomain.com/dir/index.php` ?

$$$$ = whatever is written
So, if someone try to access `mydomain.com/dir/15019510591` he will be redirected to `mydomain.com/dir/index.php`.

Please keep in mind that I want to redirect links only from `/dir/`, and not root/home page.

Comment: use htaccess for that, the 301 redirect parameter

Comment: I know I should use htaccess but dont know specified code just to redirect from /dir

Comment: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/ - all you need to know

Comment: Do you really mean a "redirect"? Or an "internal rewrite"?

Comment: Dont know a difference. I want to get people to that page, so, as far as I know its called redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*) dir/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create an `.htaccess` file in your `dir/` directory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your webserver.

[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)